# BootsFaces Erro javax.faces.FacesException: Erro de expressão

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, jsf, spring, spring-boot, bootsfaces

Segue o erro

```
javax.faces.FacesException: Erro de expressão: Objeto denominado: net.bootsfaces.component.Button não encontrado.
```

Pom

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>net.bootsfaces</groupId>
            <artifactId>bootsfaces</artifactId>
            <version>0.7.0</version>
        </dependency>
```

Minha página

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
    xmlns:b="http://bootsfaces.net/ui">

<h:head>

</h:head>

<h:body>

    <b:button value="test boostfaces"></b:button>

</h:body>

</html>
```

**estou usando spring boot com jsf**

Comment: Verifique se a biblioteca foi realmente baixada

Answer (score 1):

Seu exemplo funciona perfeitamente na minha máquina:
(veja - https://github.com/stephanrauh/BootsFaces-Examples/tree/master/Button).

Talvez o erro seja causado pela bota `spring`? Ou talvez o seu `BootsFaces.jar` seja corrupto. Tente excluí-lo do diretório `.m2` e baixá-lo novamente.

Comment: Stephan umps was I who created the issue https://github.com/TheCoder4eu/BootsFaces-OSP/issues/189#issuecomment-144852546
on the boot with integrated spring bootsfaces.

Comment: @JoseVieiraNeto I know :).  But I wanted to provide a link to our bugtracker, hoping to help other readers when we've found the solution at last.

Comment: thanks for the return, there are few that give the support that you give :)